# Reading more than one integer on a line in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So I have a button which reads a file, and puts the contents of that file into a list box. When I press the button this is what is shows:

Jim 6 8 9

Tim 7 5 6

Bill 4 10 8

What I want to do is make a separate button which adds each of the person's scores and then finds the average of them. Once it has calculated the average of the person then I want the average to be in the place of the 3 scores.

The code that I have at the moment only takes the first score of each person and then adds all of them and shows the result in a messagebox.

This is my code at the moment:

```
Dim scorevalues As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(file1)
        Dim scores As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, "\d+")
        If scores.Success Then
            scorevalues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(scores.Value))
        End If
    Next
    listbox1.DataSource = scorevalues

    Dim Scoretots As Integer = 0

    For scores2 = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1
        Scoretots = Scoretots + listbox.Items(scores2)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Total: " & Scoretots.ToString)
```

This is what my code produces:

6

7

4

And then a messagebox shows 28

Comment: Split the line at the whitespace, discard the first element of the array returned, convert the three scores to integers and then calc the average

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902255/working-out-averages-of-numbers-in-a-list-box-line/29902583#29902583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you going.  It's the same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902255/working-out-averages-of-numbers-in-a-list-box-line/29902583#29902583

```
Sub Main()
    Dim scores As String = "Bill 10 9 8"
    Dim score As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(scores, "\d+")

    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To score.Count - 1
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(score.Item(i).Value)
        Console.WriteLine(score.Item(i).Value)
    Next
    Dim average = sum / score.Count
    Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", average)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Should the dim scores as string be the list box not what I put. Would I have to convert the list box into a string if I wanted the lisbox to be in the place where u put Bill

Comment: @Bradon This is a code sample to get you in the right direction, it is not intended for direct use to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main problem is that your regex call is only catching the first match.
Change the variable "scores" to a MatchCollection and use the Matches function of the regex function.
Then, you can use For...Each to parse through the matches and add them to the list, compute your averages, etc.

Comment: When I use the matchcollection and the matches these part of the code are then underlinedin blue; If scores.Success Then and also; scorevalues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(scores.Value))

Comment: it says that they are not a member of matchcollection

Comment: That 2nd answer up there basically answered it for you. I was trying just to give you hints so you could figure part of it, yourself, since you're a student. I don't believe there's any real learning accomplished when the entire answer is just given to you.