# Reading seperate integers in a line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I have a line of text and integers like this: Text 10 9 8

My code so far reads integers like this:

1

10

109

1098

My Code:

```
Dim total As String
    For x = 0 To listbox1.Items.Count - 1

        For Each ch As Char In listbox1.Items(x)

            If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                total = String.Concat(total & ch)
                listbox1.Items.Add(total)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I want my code to read the integers like this:

10 9 8

Thanks

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905092/reading-more-than-one-integer-on-a-line-in-a-listbox) from the same user.

Comment: @Blackwood I know but this is using a different code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Your Idea was good, you just added the `Items.add` at the wrong point.

```
    Dim total As String
    For x = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        For Each ch As Char In ListBox1.Items(x)

            If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
                total = String.Concat(total & ch)
            End If
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Add(total)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: then you can close the question

Comment: If this is iterating each character, then how would this work if one of your original numbers was 10. This would show 1,0,9,8 instead of 10,9,8